# Can I use R to get a category count for every time an item in a vector pertains to a certain category?

Tags: r, vector, count, grouping, categories

I am a novice R user hoping for some help:

I want to write some code where I can input a vector and determine how many times each item fell within a category. For example, if I had three categories in a data frame and a vector in question:

````
```
fruits<-c("Apple","Banana","Pear")
vegetables<-c("Broccoli","Spinach","Peas")
flowers<-c("Rose","Daisy","lily")

df<-cbind(fruits,vegetables,flowers)

df

vectorinquestion<-c("Banana","Peas","Apple")
```
````

What kind of code can I use to get the output of:

```
Fruit = 2
Vegetable = 1
Flower = 0
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I am trying to learn new functions, so this would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop apply `%in%`, creating a logical matrix.

```
logical_matrix<-sapply(df, function(x) vectorinquestion %in% x)
> logical_matrix
     fruits vegetables flowers
[1,]   TRUE      FALSE   FALSE
[2,]  FALSE       TRUE   FALSE
[3,]   TRUE      FALSE   FALSE
```

Then you can loop apply a function to sum your TRUEs for every column:

```
> colSums(logical_matrix)
    fruits vegetables    flowers 
         2          1          0
```

All in a one-liner:

```
colSums(sapply(df, function(x) vectorinquestion %in% x)
```

With `purrr`:

```
df%>%map(~vectorinquestion %in% .)%>%cbind.data.frame()%>%colSums()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! One follow-up question I have is how to delete columns that result in colSum = 0?

Comment: for that you can add `%>% subset(., .!=0)`to the end of the code

Comment: As in: `df%>%map(~vectorinquestion %in% .)%>%cbind.data.frame()%>%colSums()%>% subset(., .!=0)`